# Topological classification of the Kane-Mele model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, topology, topological-insulators

Where should the [Kane-Mele Model](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=kane+mele+model) fall in the 10-fold way topological classification? I see that it is on a honeycomb lattice which is bipartite and thus has particle-hole symmetry. Going by that argument it should either be in the C or D class?

Comment: It is in class AII.

Comment: I thought class A2 is for 2-D TIs. However, Kane-Mele model also has particle-hole symmetry and not necessarily has time-reversal (as only spin conservation is needed) so it should not fall into A2 right?

Comment: Kane-Mele model is an example of 2D TI, so it certainly belongs to class AII. In that case, it is topologically nontrivial when both charge conservation and time-reversal symmetry are present, and no spin conservation is needed. You can also ignore the time-reversal (even if the model has it), and focus on the spin conservation, then it belongs to a different class (and also topologically nontrivial). You can also consider particle-hole if you like, but neither of the previously mentioned topological classification relies on the particle-hole.

Comment: So perhaps the more precise statement is that the model has all of the following internal symmetries: U(1) charge conservation, time-reversal squared to -1, spin conservation and particle-hole. Depending on what you care about, it could be put into different classes.

Comment: As a general question, what's the difference between particle-hole symmetry squaring to +1 or -1?

Comment: Particle-hole symmetry comes naturally with BdG Hamiltonians. Class D means PH squares to 1, and an example would be spinless fermions with p-wave pairing. Class C has PH squares to -1, and the usual spin-singlet superconductors (s-wave, d-wave, ...) belong to this class.

Comment: Is there any relation between bipartite lattices and superconductivity? Both possess particle-hole symmetry, so does that mean if I am to go about looking for a superconducting material bipartite helps?